# XPATH to select parent node along with child node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have below xml file wherein I want to select hostname,instance name, instance type using XPATH

```
<root>
<hosts>
    <host id="11">
        <name>ABC</name>
        <instances>
            <instance id="11-1">
                <name>raj</name>
                <type>linux</type>
                <date>2017</date>
            </instance>
            <instance id="11-2">
                <name>raj1</name>
                <type>linux</type>
                <date>2017</date>
            </instance>
        </instances>
    </host>
    <host id="12">
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <instances>
            <instance id="12-1">
                <name>rahul</name>
                <type>solaris</type>
                <date>2017</date>
            </instance>
        </instances>
    </host>
</hosts>
</root>
```

I have tried below XPATH which is selecting instance name and type but not sure how to print host name along with instance name and type.

```
//hosts/host/instances/instance/*[self::name or self:: type]/text()
```

It selects the below result.

```
    raj
    linux
    raj1
    linux
    rahul
    solaris
```

However, I want output like below which has host name included

```
    ABC
    raj
    linux
    raj1
    linux
    XYZ
    rahul
    solaris
```

Comment: FYI, `//` is quite expensive here -- it tells your XPath engine it needs to search for `hosts` elements anywhere in the tree, instead of only directly under `root`. In some engines there's an index for that kind of lookup (BaseX comes to mind), but that's by no means a universal feature.

Comment: (so if efficiency is important to you, consider `/root/hosts` instead of `//hosts`).

Answer (score 2):

The following (using the `|` operator to combine the sets of elements selected by any of three queries) will do:

```
  //hosts/host[./instances/instance/name or ./instances/instance/type]/name/text()
| //hosts/host/instances/instance/name/text()
| //hosts/host/instances/instance/type/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include output for `hostname` also, try below:

```
//hosts/host//*[self::name or self:: type]/text()
```

Comment: Hmm. This probably does do what the OP *wants*, but doesn't do what they *specify* (which, if read literally, indicates that only the `name`s which are under a `host` which has either an `name` or `type` attached to an `instance` should be included).

Comment: Yep, this could return wrong output in case of `type` node under `host`... Otherwise this should be an acceptable solution

Comment: I was more concerned with whether the `name` of a `host` with no instances should be included -- the way I read the OP they're implying that it shouldn't, though that could well be an unintended consequence of the way they chose to pose the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result by using any one of below solution -

### **Solution - 1(Full Path) - you can skip root:**

/root/hosts/host/name[text()]|/root/hosts/host/instances/instance/*[self::name or self::type]

### **Solution - 2(Full Path) with separate query for each result:**

/root/hosts/host/name[text()] |/root/hosts/host/instances/instance/name[text()]|/root/hosts/host/instances/instance/type[text()]

### **Solution - 3(Node Path)**

//host/name[text()]|//instance/*[self::name | self::type]

### **Solution - 4(Node Path)**

//host/*[self::name]|//instance/*[self::name | self::type]

Hope above is helpful.